# Gravity form 7 map field

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, gravityforms

I am using a gravity form on the registration page which has a file upload field. I want that file upload field to be editable on the user edit account page. Is it possible?

Thanks.

Comment: Is the "user edit account" page on the frontend or do you mean the "Your Profile" field in the WordPress admin?

Comment: Hi @DavefromGravityWiz it is per customer edit account.

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't understood your answer. Does the user edit their account on the Your Profile page in the WordPress admin or on a form on the frontend of the website? If the latter, what plugin is powering that frontend form?